# centos apache not serving 2nd virtual host

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7

I have setup centos with apache, enabled ssl and setup lets encrypt cert( followed this guide for ssl https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-centos-7). And used this guide to setup a new virtual host (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-centos-7) I cannot get my 2nd virtual host to be served. it seems like it keeps using the default ssl virtual host(which seemed to have been created after installing mod_ssl). Below are my config files

### Default ssl virtual host /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf

```
ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log  
TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log  
LogLevel warn  
SSLEngine on  
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3  
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!SEED:!IDEA  
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt   
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key  
<Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">    
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars  
</Files>  
<Directory /var/www/html/var/www/cgi-bin>  
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars  
</Directory>  
BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \  
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \  
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0  
CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \  
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"  
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

### 2nd SSL Virtual Host /etc/httpd/sites-available/example.co.za.conf

```
ServerName example.example.co.za
ServerAlias example.co.za
DocumentRoot /var/www/example.co.za/html
ErrorLog /var/www/example.co.za/log/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/example.co.za/log/requests.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.co.za [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.example.co.za
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

### updated config requested

/etc/http/conf/httpd.conf

```
Listen 80  
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf  
User apache  
Group apache  
ServerAdmin root@localhost  
<Directory />  
    AllowOverride none  
    Require all denied  
</Directory>  
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"  
<Directory "/var/www">  
    AllowOverride None  
    Require all granted  
</Directory>  
<Directory "/var/www/html">  
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks  
AllowOverride None  
    Require all granted  
</Directory>  
<IfModule dir_module>  
    DirectoryIndex index.html  
</IfModule>  
<Files ".ht*">  
    Require all denied  
</Files>  
ErrorLog "logs/error_log"  
LogLevel warn  
<IfModule log_config_module>  
 LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined  
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common  
<IfModule logio_module>  
     LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio  
    </IfModule>  
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined  
</IfModule>  
<IfModule alias_module>  
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"  
</IfModule>  
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">  
    AllowOverride None  
    Options None  
    Require all granted  
</Directory>  
<IfModule mime_module>  
  TypesConfig /etc/mime.types  
AddType application/x-compress .Z  
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz  
    AddType text/html .shtml  
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml  
</IfModule>  
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8  
<IfModule mime_magic_module>  
   MIMEMagicFile conf/magic  
</IfModule>  
EnableSendfile on  
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf  
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf  
Include /etc/httpd/sites-available/example.co.za-le-ssl.conf
```

/etc/http/conf.d/ssl.conf

```
Listen 443 https  
SSLPassPhraseDialog exec:/usr/libexec/httpd-ssl-pass-dialog  
SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/run/httpd/sslcache(512000)  
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300  
SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom  256  
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin  
SSLCryptoDevice builtin  
<VirtualHost _default_:443>  
ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log  
TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log  
LogLevel warn  
SSLEngine on  
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3  
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!SEED:!IDEA  
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt  
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key  
<Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">  
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars  
</Files>  
<Directory /var/www/html/var/www/cgi-bin>  
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars  
</Directory>  
BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \  
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \  
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0  
CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \  
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"  
DocumentRoot /var/www/html  
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/httpd/sites-available/example.co.za-le-ssl.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>  
<VirtualHost *:443>  
    ServerName example.example.co.za  
    ServerAlias example.co.za  
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.co.za/html  
    ErrorLog /var/www/example.co.za/log/error.log  
    CustomLog /var/www/example.co.za/log/requests.log combined  
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.example.co.za/cert.pem  
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.example  
.co.za/privkey.pem  
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf  
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.example.co.za/chain.pem  
</VirtualHost>  
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please also provide the `<virtualhost>` lines

Comment: and: did you create symlink from `sites-enabled/example.co.za.conf` to `sites-available/example.co.za.conf ` using `a2ensite example.co.za`?

Comment: best way for me to see if symlink has been created? would it just be a case of both .conf files being in both sites enabled and available?

Comment: Just run `ls -l` on that dir

Comment: root@examplesvc /etc/httpd/sites-available $ ls -l
total 12
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 506 May  2 04:58 example.co.za.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 650 May  2 04:58 example.co.za-le-ssl.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 252 May  2 12:55 dev.conf

Comment: when i view the contents of the sites-enabled location I do not see the example.co.za-le-ssl.conf?

Comment: Why do you have `sites-enabled` and `sites-available` directories in the first place? CentOS doesn't have this directory structure, it's a debian thing. Anyway, make sure the config file is loaded. Apart from that there is nothing we can do to help you without seeing more of the config.

Comment: the guide i referenced above guided me on creating those 2 directories? I can see the config file of the virtual host being referenced in httpd.conf as Include /etc/httpd/sites-available/example.co.za-le-ssl.conf. The virtual host I suspect is causing the issue does state "Handles the name-based server on all addresses" so perhaps this vhost is catcthing all the ssl traffic? Can I simply go and delete it? I will post the config shortly

Comment: Please edit your question to add more information. Don't use the comments.

Comment: edit done in the questions section

Comment: how do i get feedback on this?